# Perform Atomic Block Transactions in Rails with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, mongoid

I'm using *Rails 4.1.4* and *Mongoid* in my app.

I just wanted to know if there's a way to perform a block transaction atomically using *Mongoid* in *Rails*.

To make things clear, suppose I have this:

```
some_model_instance = SomeModel.find(some_id)
some_model_instance.some_attribute = "Some Attribute Value"
some_model_instance.save
other_model_instance = OtherModel.find(other_id)
other_model_instance.other_attribute = "Other Attribute Value"
other_model_instance.save
```

I want to wrap that code in a single atomic transaction, I mean, if something goes wrong I want neither of both instances (some_model_instance, other_model_instance) to be saved to the database.

I've seen that with *ActiveRecord* is somehow like this:

```
SomeModel.transaction do
    # do stuff I did above
end
```

Does that work also with *Mongoid*?.

Thanks for any help!!!.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't have transactions so you have to do it yourself like a caveman.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**CLOSED QUESTION**

**MongoDB** does not support transactions. It only performs atomic operations for a single document. So there's no way to make an *"Atomic Block Transaction"* with **Mongoid**.

Best.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but just adding an update for future visitors. MongoDB has introduced multi-document transactions which help to bundle multiple document transactions as one.

From Mongo's documentation:

> For situations that require atomicity of reads and writes to multiple
> documents (in a single or multiple collections), MongoDB supports
> multi-document transactions. With distributed transactions,
> transactions can be used across multiple operations, collections,
> databases, documents, and shards.

Here is the reference for details: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions